# Isomorphism between two group presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have these two presentations that are supposed to indicate the same group:
$$\langle a,b \mid a^3=b^2\rangle$$
$$\langle x,y \mid xyx=yxy\rangle$$
Does anybody know how can set the isomorphism up?
Thank you!

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle a,b \mid a^3=b^2\rangle,$ not $<a,b|a^3=b^2>.$ Note \langle, \mid, \rangle. $\qquad$

Comment: Have you tried drawing the caylies graph?

Comment: I didn't do cayley's graphs. Would it be easier?

Comment: This is really not very difficult. You should try and do it yourself.

Comment: You are right, once you've seen it it's really easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $\langle x,y \mid xyx=yxy\rangle$, we have $xyx=yxy$, so $(xyx)(yxy)=(xyx)(xyx)$, so $(xy)(xy)(xy)=(xyx)(xyx)$, so by letting $a=xy$ and $b=xyx$ we have $a^3=b^2$, so you can deduce the isomorphism wanted :
$$\langle a,b \mid a^3=b^2\rangle\longrightarrow \langle x,y \mid xyx=yxy\rangle\\a\mapsto xy\\b\mapsto xyx\\x\leftarrow\!\shortmid a^{-1}b\\y\leftarrow\!\shortmid b^{-1}a^2$$

Comment: $y$ is actually $ba^{-1}$.

Comment: actually it is $b^{-1}a^2$

Comment: umm..those are the same (given the relation in the group)

Comment: my bad sorry ${}{}$